# compare multiple specific columns of all rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to compare the particular columns of all the rows, if they are unique extract the value to the new column otherwise 0.

If the example dateframe as follows:

```
A      B      C  D  E  F
13348  judte  1  1  1  1
54871  kfzef  1  1  0  1
89983  hdter  4  4  4  4
7543   bgfd   3  4  4  4
```

The result should be as follows:

```
A      B      C  D  E  F Result
13348  judte  1  1  1  1  1
54871  kfzef  1  1  0  1  0
89983  hdter  4  4  4  4  4
7543   bgfd   3  4  4  4  0
```

I am pleased to hear some suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
cols = ['C','D','E','F']

df['Result'] = np.where(df[cols].eq(df[cols[0]], axis=0).all(axis=1), df[cols[0]], 0)
print (df)
       A      B  C  D  E  F  Result
0  13348  judte  1  1  1  1       1
1  54871  kfzef  1  1  0  1       0
2  89983  hdter  4  4  4  4       4
3   7543   bgfd  3  4  4  4       0
```

**Detail**:

First compare all column filtered by list of columns names by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with first column of cols `df[cols[0]]`:

```
print (df[cols].eq(df[cols[0]], axis=0))
      C      D      E      F
0  True   True   True   True
1  True   True  False   True
2  True   True   True   True
3  True  False  False  False
```

Then check if all `True`s per row by [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
print (df[cols].eq(df[cols[0]], axis=0).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

And last use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for assign first column values for `True`s and `0` for `False`.

Comment: @jezrael-Thank you very much. Please kindly check my edited question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `apply` with [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) as:

```
df['Result'] = df[['C','D','E','F']].apply(lambda x: x[0] if x.nunique()==1 else 0,1)
```

Or using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Result'] = np.where(df[['C','D','E','F']].nunique(1)==1,df['C'],0)
```

---

```
print(df)
       A      B  C  D  E  F  Result
0  13348  judte  1  1  1  1       1
1  54871  kfzef  1  1  0  1       0
2  89983  hdter  4  4  4  4       4
3   7543   bgfd  3  4  4  4       0
```