# Compare 70% of rows of particular columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to compare the particular columns of all the rows or else 70% of all the rows, if they are unique extract that value otherwise 0 to the new column.

If the example dataframe as follows:

```
A      B           C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L   
32145  Basket      2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2
43290  Red ball    1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1
32891  wht ball    4  4  4  0  4  0  4  0  4  4
45328  grn ball    1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1
34531  blk ball    6  6  6  6  0  0  0  0  6  0
```

The result should be as follows:

```
  A      B         C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M    
32145  Basket      2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2 (100% of rows are similar)
43290  Red ball    1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 (80% of rows are similar)
32891  wht ball    4  4  4  0  4  0  4  0  4  4  4 (70% of rows are similar)
45328  grn ball    1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1 (90% of rows are similar)
34531  blk ball    6  6  6  6  0  0  0  0  6  0  0 (only 50% of rows are similar)
```

I have used the below answer for finding 100% of the rows are similar.
[compare multiple specific columns of all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044726/compare-multiple-specific-columns-of-all-rows)
I would like to find if atleast 70% of all the rows are similar otherwise 0.
The consideration of rows number may vary as it is not constant all the time.

I want the unique values (only if and above 70% of the rows are similar) in the resulted row otherwise 0. (from above example 'M' column)

Pleased to know some suggestions.

Comment: Each row contains only 2 unique values or there can be any number of unique values?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar - there can be any number of unique values or in some cases may be no unique values at all. I want to consider only, if atleast 70% of all the rows are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
n= float(len(df.iloc[:, 2:].columns.values))
df['ratio']=df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x: collections.Counter(x.values).most_common(1)[0][1]/n,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
       A         B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  I.1  K  ratio
0  32145    Basket  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2    2  2    1.0
1  43290  Red ball  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1    1  1    0.8
2  32891  wht ball  4  4  4  0  4  0  4  0    4  4    0.7
3  45328  grn ball  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1    1  1    0.9
4  34531  blk ball  6  6  6  6  0  0  0  0    6  0    0.5
```

Performance Metrics:

```
df=(pd.concat([df]*10000,ignore_index=True))
```

My Proposed Solution:

```
start = time.time()
n= float(len(df.iloc[:, 2:].columns.values))
df['ratio']=df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x: collections.Counter(x.values).most_common(1)[0][1]/n,axis=1)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

O/P: 0.7386555671691895
```

@jpp's solution:

```
start = time.time()
arr = df.iloc[:, 2:]
modes = stats.mode(arr.mask(arr.eq(0)), 1)[0].ravel()
df['ratio'] = arr.eq(modes, axis=0).mean(1)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

O/P: 1.281557559967041
```

@Sandeep Kadapa's Solution:

```
start = time.time()
d = (df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(pd.value_counts, 1).drop(0, 1).max(1)/df.iloc[:, 2:].shape[1])
df['L'] = np.where(d>0.5, df.iloc[:, 2:].max(1), 0)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)

O/P: 73.34089946746826
```

Comment: Be *very* careful with your timings. Comparing like-for-like with a large number of rows, `scipy.stats` is a factor or two more efficient. Among other things, you should use `timeit`, increase the number of rows, and ensure your logic is doing the same things. See my post for benchmarking which incorporates these factors.

Comment: @jpp- Thanks for your info, I'll take more careful in future while doing timings. For this, `df=(pd.concat([df]*10000,ignore_index=True))` still your code gives `1.281` and mine returns `0.7386`. Anyway Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Have you adjusted to exclude the mask, i.e. the new `mode_ratio` function in my answer?

Comment: OK. Sadly, I can't reproduce. I assume you are using `%timeit` [can't open your notebook].

Comment: @jpp- even with your bench mark code,

`77.2 ms ± 4.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`--> My snippet
`123 ms ± 5.68 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`-->your snippet. I'm wondering how I'm getting a different result from yours :(

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the mode by row via [`scipy.stats.mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html#scipy.stats.mode) and then take the means. This example explicitly ignores `0` values via [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html). Excluding this mask (as per benchmarking below), if permitted, will see a performance improvement.

```
from scipy import stats

arr = df.iloc[:, 2:]
modes = stats.mode(arr.mask(arr.eq(0)), 1)[0].ravel()
df['ratio'] = arr.eq(modes, axis=0).mean(1)

print(df)

       A         B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  ratio
0  32145    Basket  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2    1.0
1  43290  Red ball  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1    0.8
2  32891  wht ball  4  4  4  0  4  0  4  0  4  4    0.7
3  45328  grn ball  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1    0.9
4  34531  blk ball  6  6  6  6  0  0  0  0  6  0    0.5
```

#### Performance benchmarking

For a large number of rows vs columns, and using a like-for-like algorithm, `scipy.stats.mode` outperforms `collections.Counter`:

```
from scipy.stats import mode
from collections import Counter

def counter_ratio(df):
    n= float(len(df.iloc[:, 2:].columns.values))
    df['ratio']=df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda x: Counter(x.values).most_common(1)[0][1]/n,axis=1)
    return df

def mode_ratio(df):
    arr = df.iloc[:, 2:].values
    df['ratio'] = np.mean(arr == mode(arr, 1)[0], axis=1)
    return df

n = 10**4
df = pd.concat([df]*n, ignore_index=True)

%timeit counter_ratio(df.copy())  # 1.88 s per loop
%timeit mode_ratio(df.copy())     # 32.7 ms per loop
```